# Error al crear un jar con la libreria sikuli

Tags: java, sikuli

Tengo un proyecto de automatizacion en java y estoy utilizando eclipse con la libreria sikuli. Estoy intentndo crear el JAR para poderlo ejecutar, pero le doy click al JAR y no hace nada.

[image: opcion de crear JAR][image: voy a crear el jar][image: una vez creado el jar le doy click para ejecutar pero el no hace nada]

[image: libreria sikuli]

Comment: Porque estarías queriendo ejecutar el .jar de la dependencia de tu proyecto por separado de la ejecución de tu proyecto? Si interpreté mal y lo que estás tratando de ejecutar es **RobotNITDian**, probaste hacer un `build` del proyecto a ver que error te tira?

Answer (score -1):

Creo que el que el proyecto debe de tener un archivo MANIFEST.MF el cual le dice al .jar que clase de entre todas las que tienes en tus proyecto cual ejecutar

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```